# Strictly singular operator are completely continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I'm trying to prove than "compact" $\Leftrightarrow$ "finitely strictly compact" $\Leftrightarrow$ "strictly compact" on Hilbert spaces.

> To be clear, a bounded operator $T \colon X \to Y$ between two Banach is **strictly singular** iff :
> for all $\epsilon >0$ and all infinite dimensional (closed) subset $E \subset X$ , their exists
> $v \in E$ s.t $\|Tv\| \leq \epsilon \|v\|$.
>
> A a bounded operator $T \colon X \to Y$ between two Banach is
> **completely continuous** iff : for all $(v_n)_n \subset X$ weakly convergent to $v \in X$ we have  $\|Tv_n-Tv\| \rightarrow 0$.

I need to prove that **strict singularity implies complete continuity** if X=Y and X is a Hilbert.

Using Kato's book "PERTURBATION THEORY FOR NULLITY, DEFICIENCY AND OTHER
QUANTITIES OF LINEAR OPERATORS" we can prove that that

> The set of all strictly singular operators $(X \rightarrow X)$ is a
> closed two-sided ideal of the ring of all bounded linear operators.

Next, Kato say

> From this and the fact that the identity operator  of X is not
> strictly singular if $\dim X = \infty$ it follows that the strict
> singularity implies complete continuity if $X=Y$ and $X$ is a Hilbert.

It let me think that the proof of this fact is direct but I don't see why ! Also, I don't see why we need Hilbert space. We need it to prove than "complete continuity" $\Rightarrow$ "compact" but where do we need it in this quote ?

Thanks !

Comment: It is "To prove" instead of "To proove".

Comment: You can use Rosenthal's theorem. Alternatively, since a Hilbert space is reflexive, its unit ball is weakly compact, so you can use Eberlein-Smulian theorem.

Comment: @OnurOktay Which implication are you talking ? I've aldeary used Eberlein-Smulian theorem to prove that "complete continuity implies compacity". Should I use it again to prove that "strict singularity implies complete continuity" ?